# Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function - jsqlite

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I am trying to transfer an android project from Eclipse to android studio. The project uses a special database called jsqlite. In this library there is a class called jsqlite.Database which has some native functions. When I mouse over those native function I get the message:

> Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function Java_jsqlite_Database__1open
>   Reports native method declarations in Java where no
>   corresponding JNI function is found in the project

This message is for this native function:

```
private native void _open(String filename, int mode)
    throws jsqlite.Exception;
```

There are 3 .so files inside the project in those paths:

```
app\libs\armeabi\libjsqlite.so
app\libs\armeabi-v7a\libjsqlite.so
app\libs\x86\libjsqlite.so
```

So my guess is that there are on the wrong path. I tried to move them to other positions with no success. Any ideas what to try next?

**UPDATE**

This is my projects structure:

```
>app
 ->manifest
 ->java
   ->com.myapp.data
   ->jsqlite
 ->jniLibs
 ->res
```

Answer (score 2):

You are putting the libraries in the wrong folder.

This should be the correct path:

```
..\YourProject\app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi\libjsqlite.so
..\YourProject\app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi-v7a\libjsqlite.so
..\YourProject\app\src\main\jniLibs\x86\libjsqlite.so
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried all possible paths but I still get the same error. I updated my post with the file structure of my project, if you want check it out.

Comment: Have you followed the project structure of the example project [here](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-android/spatialite-for-android-3.0.1.zip)? Using Android Studio, you should have 2 separate modules, one representing your app (spatialite-android), the other one representing the library (spatialite-android-library)

Comment: No I haven't. Can you guide me please?

Comment: Sorry, i never used this library. Read here how to import a module library https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#AddDependency. Use the File->New->Import module function described here

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: no problem, hope you can arrive to a solution at some point. But let me say that the library configuration is not the easiest for sure ;)